# Cross-correlation estimation in MATLAB using a method similar to pwelch for the PSD

Tags: matlab, power-spectral-density, autocorrelation, cross-correlation, periodogram

Is there a function in MATLAB to estimate the cross correlation function of two wide-sense stationary signals (or the autocorrelation of the signal with itself) in a way similar to the estimation of the PSD using PWELCH?

I mean an estimate using shorter overlapping intervals and an averaging process to reduce noise .

Comment: The cross power spectral density is defined as the Fourier transform of the cross-correlation. Maybe you could just perform an IFFT on PSD if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I don't think it is a straightforward operation to pass through the PSD, although it would make sense